# CBPeripheralManager will not power on when called to

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

My code keeps getting stuck when i call this if statement to check the peripheral state.  When I change the operation from != to == it goes through and performs the NSLog but the debugger says the peripheral manager is not turned on.  How do i correct this?

I first power on the peripheral manager in the viewDidLoad method:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

// Start up the CBPeripheralManager
self.peripheralManager = [[CBPeripheralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil];

NSLog(@"viewDidLoad");
}
```

Then I call the peripheralManagerDidUpdateState method:

```
- (void)peripheralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBPeripheralManager *)peripheralManager
{
    // Opt out from any other state
if (self.peripheralManager.state != CBPeripheralManagerStatePoweredOn)
{
    return;
}

// We're in CBPeripheralManagerStatePoweredOn state...
NSLog(@"self.peripheralManager powered on.");

// ... so build our service.


// Then the service
CBMutableService *transferService = [[CBMutableService alloc] initWithType:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:TRANSFER_SERVICE_UUID] primary:YES];


// And add it to the peripheral manager
[self.peripheralManager addService:transferService];
}
```

I have my startAdvertising command called later in the program as a result of a IBAction/button being pushed:

```
- (IBAction)advertise:(id)sender
{
if(self.peripheralManager.state == CBPeripheralManagerStatePoweredOn)
{
[self.peripheralManager startAdvertising:@{ CBAdvertisementDataServiceUUIDsKey : @[[CBUUID UUIDWithString:TRANSFER_SERVICE_UUID]] }];
[self.peripheralManager startAdvertising:@{ CBAdvertisementDataTxPowerLevelKey : @(YES)}];
}
}
```

By calling startAdvertising AFTER checking the peripheral state instead of BEFORE have anything to do with this error?

Comment: You say "I call the `peripheralManagerDidUpdateState:` method." Are _you_ calling it, or do you mean that it's called by the `CBPeripheralManager`?  In `peripheralManagerDidUpdateState:`, what is the value of `self.peripheralManager.state`? Have you checked that Bluetooth is on?

Comment: Well its just a method in the program: - (void)peripheralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBPeripheralManager *)peripheralManager  Does it not get executed if i dont call for it to?

Comment: You don't call this method. The `CBPeripheralManager` instance (i.e. Core Bluetooth) calls it when the peripheral manager's state has changed.